# How do I force Chromium's window buttons to the right side when in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, chromium, window-buttons

I prefer Gnome Shell as a DE. The migration from Unity to Gnome Shell in 11.10 is flawless but there is an annoying bug with Chromium. The buttons on Chromium stay on the left side where Gnome Shell uses the right side. Any ideas on how to force Chromium have the buttons on the right side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish that simply by editing gconf (which chromium uses) like this:

`gconftool /apps/metacity/general/button_layout -t string -s "menu:minimize,maximize,close"`
You can leave the "menu" if you don't need it, however the colon is needed as a separator between the left and right sides of the titlebar.
The changes should be visible right away, if they're not just log out and back in.

PS: I know that Ubuntu Tweak does exactly the same, but I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to post this as a comment on Geppettvs' answer, which I originally intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answers to this questions, which may be helpful for you, I am reproducing only one of these over here for your convenience but all the answers provided by several users and their experiences may give you a clue on how to manage this issue:

1. [How can I place Gedit's tab close buttons on the left?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25485/how-can-i-place-gedits-tab-close-buttons-on-the-left/25501#25501)
2. [Change color of window buttons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27142/change-color-of-window-buttons/27144#27144)
3. [Change the default Downloads directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60161/change-the-default-downloads-directory/60179#60179)
4. [How to make the window manager to show the X - [ ] not on left top corner but bottom left or bottom right corner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60409/how-to-make-the-window-manager-to-show-the-x-not-on-left-top-corner-but-bot/60412#60412)
   posted here for your convenience:

> Depending on your window decorator I am sure you can, in example,
>   using emerald to create your own theme which will allow you to define
>   where do you wish to place these controls.
>
> Anyway, [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) will allow you to set the place on where
>   these controls are displayed on your windows top corners, left or
>   right, and will also allow you to re-arrange the buttons with your
>   preferences.
>
> Take a look at this screenshot: [image]
>   *This options can be found under "Window Manager Settings" in Ubuntu Tweak*
>
> I hope this help you.
>
> Good luck!

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

right click on empty space near your tabs and select 'Use System Title Bar and Borders'.

Comment: This gives you buttons on the right side but also adds a screen wasting bar.  There should just be a way to move the buttons from the left to the right without having to resort to the system title bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

That worked for me for chrome, I supose that chromium is the same